# how to I get data validation go into new row I added below the header?

Tags: excel

I have this worksheet to keep track of tasks.  I added Data Validation into a few columns to limits the dates, to make it you can only pick yes no, a look up to a different table based on value you entered in one of the cell.  I add new row in the top every time I have new entry, it would give me a blank row, I end up have to copy the row below, paste it, then remove all the values.

Row 1 is the header, I created a blank row 2, in one of the blank cell, I simply put "Copy this row", so the data validation would go into the new row.  I have not try any macro since I am not good with coding, and this sheet lives in EXCEL online, being shared with few other people.

Is there a way to add new row on top, keep the data validation and functions without using macro or VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.
Row 1 is your header.
Row 2 onwards you setup your data validation.
Then hide row 2 only (with no data, but all validations).
Then when you add new row, it actually add it as row 3, since row 2 is hidden. All data validations are there too.[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

If possible, format your data as a Table. When you add a new row to a table, the Data Validation rules and calculated formulas are automatically applied to the new row. Then you just have to enter your new data.